# MIPS: writing to $ra with instruction other than jal

Tags: mips, store, overwrite

Can a load word instruction save data to `$ra`?

Is it merely convention to reserve `ra` for return addresses or is it impossible to overwrite?

Comment: `SW` doesn't alter any registers. Perhaps you mean `LW`? In any case, this would be easy to test - just write a program that attempts to do this and run it in a simulator/emulator (or on an actual MIPS-based device if you've got access to one).

Comment: Why do you want to overwrite `$ra`? And if you did, how would you return to the instruction which should execute after `jal`?

Comment: Using $ra for return address is mostly conventional. `JAL` uses $ra, but `JALR` can use any register. Nothing prevents you from doing `MOV $ra, $t1`, or `LW $ra, xxx`.